# subshell command and capturing the exitcode

Tags: python, shell, terminal, subprocess, exit-code

in python3 i invoke a parent shell with subprocess.run:

```
output=subprocess.run(['parent.sh', *cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

then i check the returncode:

```
print("retcode =", output.returncode)
print("stdout =", output.stdout)
print("stderr =", output.stderr)
```

all good so far i catch the exitcode but what i am currently trying to catch are exitcodes from any sub/child shell scripts within the parent

the parent is generic and looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -ea

OUT="$("$@"; printf :%s "${PIPESTATUS[*]}")"

set +ea
```

so it will invoke any given .sh script and "should" return any exit codes even from nested child .sh scripts

so i tested by a nested level of 3:

```
parent.sh 
         -> child_1.sh
                      -> child_2.sh
```

i purposefully removed "child_2" so it would throw an error because it cant find it and while the stderr shows the error message "child_2.sh no such file or directory" the returncode of "output.returncode" is zero any suggestions how to catch all exitcodes? no matter how nested a parent shell is

Comment: `how to catch all exitcodes?` so exit with proper exit code of child from parents. What is PIPESTATUS doing there? There is no pipe. `and "should" return any exit codes even from nested` No, it will always exit with 0 - the exit status of last command `set +ea` will be 0. Your parent script is just invalid and ignores child exit status. I do not understand. Just remove your parent script, it is masking exit status and removing stdout, and just do `subprocess.run(cmd)` from the start.

Comment: `catch are exitcodes from any sub/child shell scripts within the parent` This is OS specific. _On linux_ you can ptrace PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK the program and capture PTRACE_EVENT_EXIT. Note that your "parent.sh" is at least 3 processes - the `$(..)` is a subshell, which is a separate process. `$(...)` exits with 0 exit status, because `printf` exits with 0. Overall, that is a workaround - the proper solution is to use proper shell scripts that exit with nonzero on errors.

Comment: I believe, the person who wrote the parent.sh script is most probably not aware that `set -e` does not transfer to the subshell, and counted on early script termination in case `"$@"` exits with non-zero exit status. This does not happen, as `set -e` is not inherited in the subshell. Related https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 . However, I do not understand what is `OUT=` and `printf` and `set -a` doing there, serving no purpose.

Comment: @KamilCuk i tried your suggestion with subprocess.run([*cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) but again the child .sh throws an error that it could not be found but the returncode is still 0

Comment: MCVE - Then post `child.sh`. You can write a shell script like `invalid_command; echo` and shell will always exit with 0 exit code.